# Retrieving the value on y-axis from a dc.js line chart using the date

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I've created a line chart in dc.js using crossfilter and simply plotting the date, value pairs on the x and y axes:

```
var parse = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(data.points, function(d) { return parse(d.date) }));
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([-1.0, 1.0]);

var ndx = crossfilter(data.points);
var dataDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return parse(d.date) });
var dataGroup = dataDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.value });

chart.group(dataGroup)
     .x(x)
     .y(y)
     ...;
```

Is there then a way to get the y-axis value of a point using the date? I know that you can retrieve the date on the x-axis for a given mouse coordinate using:

```
x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]
```

However, it doesn't seem to be as simple to access the value on the y-axis by using the x-axis date.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an array

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < yourData.length; i++) {
    arr[yourData.date] = yourData.value;
}
```

This way you would be able to access any value by doing arr[date], where date is the corresponding date to the value you want.

Comment: Technically, this should probably be an object, since you're indexing by string. But yes, I agree this is probably the best approach. There is no "map" of values built in. You could use `dataGroup.all()` to produce this object with exactly the data the chart uses.